# How to cleanly wrap a class constructor?

Tags: typescript

I'm prototyping code that would allow me to cleanly create an Angular Dialog initializer, which is passed a constructor function *and* it's arguments in a type-safe way. The following works, but it is

- difficult
- unsafer than it should be

```js
class SomeDialogClass {
    name: string;
    nachname: string;
    id: number;

    constructor(name: string, nachname: string, id: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nachname = nachname;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

// type Constructor = new (...args: unknown[]) => unknown; // <- breaks
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any; // <- This is ugly. Is there no "Constructor" utility type?

function createDialog<DialogClass extends Constructor>(classConstructor: DialogClass, ...args: ConstructorParameters<DialogClass>): InstanceType<DialogClass> {
    // everything in here is uncertain due to "any" in Constructor type
    return new classConstructor(...args);
}

const instance = createDialog(SomeDialogClass, "John", "Doe", 7);

console.log(instance);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgEQJZhPA5gYXCmgG8AoaC6AOzBQC5oIAXAJ3SpwG5zKbgALGvUat2XHhXQATBlQCuiAEbIW3CdGDwqzFnOBN4LABRDkDHWIA01MANPnRHa9NkLlLAJQl1laE37oEAB0ptAAvDYo3L6+-oEhtoK0yOE2dsnRMRRxwdKp0pkUAL6kJaQA9OV+AJ4ADil4Wjp6BiypVMgA7tBGQX1gLDgQDHJUANZU8J1UANoAul5hAHzQoxNTVJzQldAAPAC00IosyGBjEKRMdQ1NrC2G7V09fUEDQwxgVNXziyuf1VsdgdoAAVAIwQKrHAgapBaAASRg-hUKUm0AARI1tHd9IZ0asmOgQOgrjV6gB+UikABmo306C0GhOYCYaEw2BwuwwWFwBEgMGQAA9WVQpDAsc1cSwlkZQPyJTjWgxuRy+VBrC83sNoArdFKAAoDZKslgQLns3mECBLDwMeHYz7AZAg67mnn4K0rMi+HbIABuKmqcQ40HY0H4KNDMDpKiYYDDUjkKQMGP++LDuvubSu9XUJyYchYVGoTzlUEzUt6-UGEA83DKmmxoYdVCdqWAzNZKtwRgQKG7Hv51nRACl4IJ0cPUPBkJPoAB2OtUxsQeAgZBBDlGdjMR3IOtAA)

Is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkDXlw) is the "standard" way of doing this. Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I like it! I just replaced the `any[]` with an `unknown[]`, which still works fine. If you write that up as an answer I'll happily accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the constructor type `T` and then extract out the argument and instance types from it with the [`ConstructorParameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) and [`InstanceType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) utility types, the compiler won't really be able to understand what's going in inside the function body.  Those utilities are implemented as [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and conditional types that depend on generic type parameters are essentially opaque to the compiler.  It just *defers* evaluation of such types, and so it won't be able to verify the correctness of your code.

Instead, it's more straightforward for the compiler to understand if you make the function generic in the argument list type `A` and instance type `I` directly:

```
function createDialog<A extends unknown[], I>(
    classConstructor: new (...args: A) => I,
    ...args: A
): I {
    return new classConstructor(...args);
}
```

And this still works as desired from the caller's side:

```
const instance = createDialog(
    SomeDialogClass, "John", "Doe", 7
);
// const instance: SomeDialogClass
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgEQJZhPA5gYXCmgG8AoaC6AOzBQC5oIAXAJ3SpwG5zKbgALGvUat2XHhXQATBlQCuiAEbIW3CdGDwqzFnOBN4LABRDkDHWIA01MANPnRHa9NkLlLAJQl1laE37oEAB0ptAAvDYo3L6+-oEhtoK0yOE2dsnRMRRxwdKp0pkUAL6kJaQAZnJU+uhaGizIYExomNg4ADwAgtDIAB7NVFIwVQDWVPAA7lQA2gC61gCSAHxG6qCQEHhaOnoGLLLIE9BGQadgLDgQDJ1eYUvQC5bqp0Hnl9ekHgwL3r4NTHIWFRqIcNIRNttWLtDCczhcIB5uGVNNomNB2MwwNUUhFgA0mi0sLhVr4ECgMET8ODrAAiABS8EENNpqHgyGZ0AA7J9uAB6XkaSHo1FY4BmOBIQltAgbUikFEQeAgZBBNpGDFMUXIRFAA)